# Is there any command or setting to fix jupyter notebook output alignment?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I've been using jupyter notebook but, my fonts and their values are not align properly can anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?[Jupyternotebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx0af.png)

I tried to update the anaconda version and PANDAS as well but nothing works.

Comment: they are alligned on the left hand side.